# TableLayout Crashing application on android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am using TableLayout in one of my activity layout. but when I am trying to run same activity on the Lollipop it crashes.

It works perfectly on Marshmallow and Nougat.

When I tried to run it after removing TableLayout(ONLY) it worked fine in Lollipop also.

I tried removing all java code on the activity, its having same problem.

**My Crash Report**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.sovereignconsult.region.viand, PID: 19434
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null
>   object reference
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.forceUniformHeight(LinearLayout.java:1380)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1368)
>                         at android.widget.TableRow.onMeasure(TableRow.java:114)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5653)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                         at android.widget.TableLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableLayout.java:464)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>                         at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:476)
>                         at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:439)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
>                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
>                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
>                         at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1269)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                         at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:338)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
>                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
>                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5653)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5653)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5653)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5653)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5653)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2748)
>                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2030)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1174)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1395)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1062)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5873)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
>                         at com.android.internal.

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/top_bar"/>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/productscrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offeringNmae"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:textColor="@color/lildark"
            android:text="Name of Offering" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/terms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/orderTerms"
            android:layout_below="@id/offeringNmae"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>



        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/orderDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:layout_below="@id/terms"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            <TableRow
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:text="Details"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </TableRow>
            <View
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightGray"/>
            <TableRow
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/orderName"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/quantity"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:padding="3dip"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/price"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>
            </TableRow>

            <View
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightGray"/>
            <TableRow
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="Total Amount"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:id="@+id/totalamount"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/orderAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:layout_below="@id/orderDetails"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            <TableRow
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="Pickup Address"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            </TableRow>
            <View
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightGray"/>
            <TableRow
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:id="@+id/address"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/chefNote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:layout_below="@id/orderAddress">
            <TableRow
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="Note For Chef"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            </TableRow>
            <View
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightGray"/>
            <TableRow
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:id="@+id/ChefNote"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/defaultText"
    android:background="@color/defaultText"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bookbottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/PayNow"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyledefaultcolor"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

```
public class order_verification_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_verification);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error you provided indicates that you have a java.lang.NullPointerException check this link to fix it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: check where app crash starts

Comment: @YamenNassif I tried running it removing all java code on the activity. But problem is ONLY WITH `TableLayout`

Comment: @parish you said when you remove TableLayout it works. you have 3 TableLayouts. Try to delete them 1 by 1 and determine which one is causing the issue.

Comment: @YamenNassif It only works if there is not TableLayout

Comment: i know you said that you removed the java code, but there must be some code to launch the activity. can you provide it please ?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: try to extend the old Activity class not the AppCompat one

Comment: remove all `layout_height` and `layout_width` in TextView inside TableRow. This will solve your problem

Comment: this is your problem `<TableRow
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:id="@+id/address"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
            </TableRow>`

Comment: @YamenNassif and Bek Thankyou for help, I have solved it with the help of YamenNassif's Deleted answer... there was some problem with the layout. View is working now betwn TableRow

Comment: @parish I undeleted it feel free to edit it to match the solution

Comment: @YamenNassif yes sure Thankyou

Comment: @parish glad to help ^^

Comment: try to put layout_width and layout_height in textview inside tablerow. your problem reappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you removed all the java code then I would suggest something (wrote it in an answer so it fits).
You have in your code a `<View>` inside a `<TableLayout>` which I suspect to be mistaken try to adjust your code to meet this (you have the same thing in more places change it all please):

```
<TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/orderDetails"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:layout_below="@id/terms"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
                <TableRow
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:text="Details"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </TableRow>
                <View
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightGray"/>
                <TableRow
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/orderName"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/quantity"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:padding="3dip"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/price"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:text="Total Amount"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:id="@+id/totalamount"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>
                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/orderAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:layout_below="@id/orderDetails"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
                <TableRow
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:text="Pickup Address"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </TableRow>
                <View
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightGray"/>
                <TableRow
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/address"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/noteForCheifa"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:layout_below="@id/orderAddress"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
                <TableRow
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:text="Note For Chef"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </TableRow>
                <View
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightGray"/>
                <TableRow
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ChefNote"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>



            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/paymentmode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:layout_below="@id/noteForCheifa"
                android:layout_marginBottom="90dp">
                <TableRow
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:text="Select Payment Method"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </TableRow>
                <View
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightGray"/>
                <TableRow
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                    <RadioGroup
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/RGroup">
                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/SelectTezUpi"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/Tez"
                            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/paytm"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Paytm"
                            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
                    </RadioGroup>

                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

remove layout_width and layout_height or make layout_height="wrap_content" in textview inside table row

```
 <TableRow
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
        </TableRow>
```

Comment: This solution also worked for buttons embedded in a table, on api 22.